# Add-AzureAccount fails in admin powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, azure-active-directory

As the title suggests, when I run `Add-AzureAccount` in an admin powershell on my up-to-date Windows 10 machine, it fails with the following error message (after I enter my correct Azure account credentials into the sign-in page that pops up):

```
Add-AzureAccount : AADSTS50074: Strong Authentication is required.
Trace ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Correlation ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Timestamp: 2020-12-11 14:04:07Z
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AzureAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureAccount
```

What could be the cause of this problem and how could one solve it?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/migAz/issues/192 check this url

Comment: above github link not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is "Strong Authentication is required"

The problem may be that to Add an account you need to be logged in with multi factor authentication and you are not logged in with MFA.

Comment: I cannot tell if this is the right answer because I'm not able to set up MFA for my account (requires Azure AD premium). But you are probably right. So, I will mark your answer as accepted for now.

Comment: Microsoft recently made a change that MFA is available for all SKU's of Azure AD including the free version https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-licensing. You do not have all the functionality of the other SKU's but you can turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that running `Add-AzureAccount` opened a new Azure authentication pop-up window that defaulted to *Sign-in-with-GitHub* for some reason - instead of the Azure AD Tenant that my Azure Subscription belongs to - and there was *zero* indication on-screen this was the case.

So, when using `Add-AzureAccount`, **DON'T** just enter your Azure MSA's e-mail address in the popup: instead click the "Sign-in options" button *first* and make sure that it's using the correct AAD Tenant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying Add-AzureAccount command for the first time on my newly allotted laptop. I was getting exactly the same error. After a day of hit and error I figured out below command which unblocked me.

```
Add-AzureAccount -Tenant <Tenant-Id-of-the-subscription>
```

In my case, I gave the tenant id of MSFT subscription.

Documentation link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/add-azureaccount

Comment: How do you determine the Tenant Id of the subscription?